# Stuck at "ipfs process started" after running embark

Tags: go-ethereum, dapp-development, ipfs, embark

I ran the following commands,
`embark demo`
`cd embark_demo` `embark run`

```
embark info invoked /home/k00lawn/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/lib/node_modules/embark/bin/embark
embark info located /home/k00lawn/Work/projects/embark_demo/node_modules/embark/bin/embark
embark info Switching from embark@6.0.0 to embark@6.0.0

pid 23875 listening on /tmp/embark-98331801/embark.ipc
loaded plugins: embark-ipfs, embark-swarm, embark-whisper-geth, embark-geth, embark-parity, embark-profiler, embark-graph, embark-basic-pipeline
Cockpit UI available at http://localhost:55555
Blockchain node is ready
Starting Whisper node in another process
IPFS node not found, attempting to start own node
Starting ipfs process
HTTP Proxy for node endpoint ws://localhost:8546 listening on http://localhost:8555
WS Proxy for node endpoint ws://localhost:8546 listening on ws://localhost:8556
ipfs process started
```